# error: cannot find symbol in java when i try to create an object

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Buenas Tardes a todos miren es que ando aprendiedno java y pues he tenido problemas a la hora de crear un constructor ya que estyo tratando de hacer un ejercico con un banco artificial y no he dado con el problema

carpeta donde tengo los archivos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi clase Account.java:

```
package exercise;

public class Account {
    String numberAccount;
    String key;
    int cash;

    public Account(){}

    public Account(String numberAccount, String key){
        this.numberAccount = numberAccount;
        this.key = key;
        this.cash = 10000;
    }
    
}
```

y esta es mi modulo principal bank.java:

```
package exercise;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bank {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            var operando = 0;
            while (operando != 5) {
                System.out.println("Bienvenido \n1.Crear Cuenta\n2.Consignar\n3.Retiros\n4.Consulta de Saldo\n5.Salir");
                operando = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()) ;
                switch (operando) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Nombre de la cuenta:");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Ingrese la clave:");
                        String code = input.nextLine();
                        Account cuenta = new Account(name, code);
                        System.out.println("Cuenta ha sido creada");
                        break;
                
                    default:
                        System.out.println("mal ahi wacho");
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Pero lastimosamente me esta generando este error en la linea donde estoy creando el objeto:

```
**bank.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                        Account cuenta = new Account(name, code);
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class bank
2 errors
error: compilation failed**
```

Alguien que porfavor tenga los conocimientos y me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola. ¿Ambas clases están en el mismo `package`? Parecería que están en paquetes (carpetas dentro del proyecto) distintos. Por cierto, respeta la *convención de nombre*, poniendo tu nombre de clase `Bank` y el nombre de archivo `Bank.java`.

Comment: Revisa además cómo tienes organizado tu código, o si el classpath no está mal configurado o si no estás poniendo mal la ruta, en caso de que estés compilando por consola. El código del mensaje de error es distinto al código que muestras en la pregunta. En el mensaje de error la instancia que intentas crear se llama `acc1`: **`Account acc1 = new Account(name, code);`**  y en el código de la pregunta la instancia se llama `cuenta`: **`Account cuenta = new Account(name, code);`** Es evidente que estás compilando otro código, no el que nos estás mostrando en la pregunta.

Comment: ![XHTML válido](https://imgur.com/equsJaO).

Muchachos aqui dejo como tengo la carpeta organnizada

Comment: @A.Cedano de hecho ya revise y no me sale es con Account cuenta , ya lo revise

Comment: El código no debería dar ese error si ambas clases están en el mismo paquete (carpeta). Explica cómo estás depurando, si usas herramientas tales como Maven, Gradle, etc. debes verificar que no esté cogiendo un código viejo que se haya quedado en caché o en algún snapshoot anterior con código erróneo. Si es por consola, explica qué comando estás ejecutando. En cualquier caso, revisa las salidas por consola, verificando cosas como las rutas de los archivos.

Comment: PS C:\Users\andre\Desktop\andres\java\exercise> java bank.java 
@A. Cedano